# history.back() does not update location.hash in Chrome/FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I tried to build a JS script that would change the location of the page, to go back until a specific hash location is found:

```
var StopAtThisHash ='#';
var CurrentHash = window.location.hash;
var continueLoop = true;
while ((window.history.length>0) && (continueLoop))
{
        window.history.back();
        var NowWeAreAtHash = window.location.hash; //this never changes in Chrome
        //actually, always seems to:  CurrentHash  == NowWeAreAtHash;
       if(NowWeAreAtHash == StopAtThisHash)
                        continueLoop= false;
}
```

Weird enough, in Chrome and FF, the window.location.hash is not changed after back().. neither is the length of history decreased by 1 as I expected. The loop runs indefinitely, and the browser hangs up.

In IE 9 this seems to run as intended.

Any workarounds around this?

Comment: Maybe check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305069/can-you-use-hash-navigation-without-affecting-history because you can use `history.replaceState(undefined, undefined, "#hash_value")` to replace hash value

Answer (score 1):

```
function goBackHome () {
    goBackToHash(''); // Assume the home is without hash. You can use '#'.
}
function goBackToHash(hash) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (window.location.hash == hash) return;
        history.back();
        goBackToHash(hash);
    }, 0);
}
```

To overcome the problem of `while` loop, I tried use `setTimeout`, but this is usually goes further than expected... Waiting for a perfect solution.

I think there is a delay between `history.back()` and when `window.location.hash` is changed.

Another workaround is to keep the hashes in JS so that you can figure out how many steps is needed in `history.go(N)`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `window.history.back()`, `window.history.forward()` and `window.history.go()` does not changes history, just navigates back and forth. If `back()` would change length of history then you would not be able to `forward()`.

As workaround I would suggest to loop over `window.history` with `for` from last to first instead of `while`.