# How can I replace a window's URL hash with another response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, replace, attr

I am trying to change a hashed URL (document.location.hash) with the replace method, but it doesn't work.

```
$(function(){
 var anchor = document.location.hash;
 //this returns me a string value like '#categories'

  $('span').click(function(){

     $(window).attr('url').replace(anchor,'#food');
     //try to change current url.hash '#categories'
     //with another string, I stucked here.
  });

});
```

I dont want to change/refresh page, I just want to replace URL without any responses.

Note: I don't want to solve this with a href="#food" solution.

Comment: Are you just trying to change the hash? `location.hash = '#food';`

Comment: yes, with an another string like '#food'

Comment: `window` doesn't have an `url` attribute, `$(window).attr('url')` returns `undefined`. You misspelled `replace` as well and `undefined` does not have a replace method, and even if it was a string you aren't retuning it anywhere (it'd be just discarded).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté good catch. It's great when "programmers" don't notice such errors. Apparently the debug console is a secret that only _some_ programmers know about... or is SO a remote error/debug log facility? ^^'

Comment: rofl, +1 @Spooky but yeah, not everyone is very experienced with JS so I usually tell them to use Chrome's Dev Tools or [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), but as I figured OP was just showing an example of what he'd have tried, I only pointed out a couple reasons why it wouldn't work. `:P`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - "I only pointed out **a couple** reasons why it wouldn't work"... I laughed so hard. You're so kind :')

Comment: Lol, I said "a couple" because my brain tries to stop compiling when it reaches a syntax error and I could not be mentioning 'em all. `x]` But OP's code tries to illustrate what he is trying to do, so it's worth a couple points. `:)`

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: dude this is question website rigth? and i am asking questions, i can do simple mistakes, i didnt say that i am pro, what is your real problem @Spooky ?

Comment: being rude and snob wont take you anywhere @Spooky .

Comment: [chat.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Either use `location` or `window.location` instead of `document.location` as the latter is a non-standard.

```
window.location.hash = '#food';
```

This will replace the URL's hash with the value you set for it.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Comment: +1  It seems the OP was simply unaware that this method doesn't "change/refresh page".

Comment: Plugin? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @barlasapaydin By how your question currently stands, this is the only answer I can think of. If you update the question with more info I'll take another look. Meanwhile I'll grab something to eat.

Comment: @barlasapaydin ensure that the code is being called and ensure that you navigate to a fresh instance of the page (remember you have a hash in your current URL, so remove it before refreshing).

Comment: If you wish the change the hash within the URL when the user clicks an anchor tag, why not just use `<a href="#bar">Foo</a>`?

Comment: +1 Spooky, even though if he is developing a plugin, he may not be able to edit the page's source.

Comment: That's a good point, Fab. Edit your post to include his code, with your single line added - I think that's what he's waiting for.

Comment: @Spooky o really why i coundt think that !! dude i need to change it with this way.. otherwise i didnt ask this question.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338967/jquery-issue-on-extending-jquery-functionality/11339046#11339046 read this and be sure that i am not having problems with plguin.

Comment: @barlasapaydin I'm taking a look at your plugin, apparently you had a syntax error - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/5yKr6/) what is it supposed to do again? Just move the links down? And is it related to this question somehow?

Comment: @barlasapaydin Fab wasn't implying that you're having issues with a plugin - he was merely asking what your plugin's intentions are, so that he knows what the limits are (such as whether or not you have direct access to the HTML).

Comment: okey, i have got cache problem. got fixed. thank you for your answer @FabrícioMatté

Comment: @barlasapaydin No problem, also http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/5yKr6/1/ (I edited your plugin slightly, not sure if that's what you asked me for anyway)

Comment: Here's a cleaner and more well-commented version: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/5yKr6/3/). And off-topic, first downvote I have got in one of my upvoted answers so far, how cute `:)` (I'm not complaining about anonymous downvoters, but if you feel that I can improve my answer, then comment it).

Comment: Removed the `href` anchors which @Spooky suggested due to OP's new question update, oh well. That was a very nice and quick thinking to solve it though, thanks Spooky. `=]`

Comment: Thanks. I wish to point out that I upvoted your answer as soon as you posted it. Good job Fab :)

Comment: Curiously `document.location.hash` worked for me whereas `window.location.hash` did not.

Comment: Worth mentioning that including the "#" is not needed. `window.location.hash = 'food';` will also work and is the recommended way.

Answer (score 72):

You may prefer the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23924886/3137109).

The difference being that with `history.replaceState()` you don't scroll to the anchor, only replace it in the navigation bar. It's supported by all major browsers, [source](http://caniuse.com/#search=history.replaceState).

```
history.replaceState(undefined, undefined, "#hash_value")
```

Comment: This answer should be set as accepted - by using this method no change is made except the change of the hash value.
This goes double, since the original question contains this condition: "I dont want to change/refresh page, I just want to replace URL without any responses."

Comment: Indeed this solution in great, especially if there is no need to add new history entry. I also noticed that # is need to be at the end of url this line work.

Comment: Probably need something like:
    window.history.replaceState(undefined, '', `${window.location.href.split('#')[0]}#${new URLSearchParams(newParams).toString()}`)