# Update URL on AJAX request without using hash #

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, url-routing

I need functionality like the below website. When you scroll down, new stories are fetched from server using AJAX and the URL is also updated. There is no hash # in url as well.

http://qz.com/

How can I achieve this?

thanks

Comment: pushstate. However, in IE<10, you'll have to use the hash or page reloads.

Comment: I answered in a similar question. Take a look this answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358020/how-can-i-make-wordpress-infinite-scrolling-change-the-url/31243320#31243320

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.history.pushState(“state object/id”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

Still, you need to use hashes on browsers that do not support it. 
I use https://github.com/browserstate/history.js that does all the old browsers fallbacks for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try project sarus.

http://srijanlabs.github.io/sarus/

It is a framework built in angularJS to carry out similar functionality. It fetches articles as the user scrolls through the page while url mapping is maintained in browser's address bar.

Moreover, being a frontend application it is highly customizable and works with API/RSS to fetch data.