# How to: Execute infinite scroll using AngularJS and change route on every new post

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I want to build something like [qz.com](http://qz.com)

The url changes(without page refresh) when you scroll down and the data gets appended to the last post.
Trying to build it over [angular-express-seed](https://github.com/btford/angular-express-seed).

Any pointers or tutorials will help.

EDIT:
Found a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/fotuzlab/nES2q/ (forked from original)

```
elm.bind('scroll', function() {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
            }
        });
```

Seems it can do the job but now elm.bind is not working for some reason.
Any other method to so this?

Comment: Which version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12115259/149060

Comment: Its AngularJS v1.0.7.

Comment: @marfarma: I went through that link but thats not what I am looking for. Take it in this way: A page that has infinite scroll of posts and with every post the url changes. I found this http://jsfiddle.net/fotuzlab/nES2q/ but elm.bind is not working for some reason. working on it.

Comment: Now upgraded to AngularJS v1.0.8

Comment: I answered in a similar question. Take a look this answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358020/how-can-i-make-wordpress-infinite-scrolling-change-the-url/31243320#31243320

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering own question in case it helps someone.

Instead of writing a complete custom directive to achieve the purpose, integrated a controller with [inview](https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview) directive.

1. Added div in partial which calls a controller loadnext().

   <\div in-view="loadNext($inview);" </div>
2. Controller calculates the next article and pushes it in view.

   $scope.posts.push(data)

This can be seen working at http://sarus.srijanlabs.com

This project has been open sourced under the name Sarus. Complete code can be checked there
https://github.com/srijanlabs/sarus

All thanks to my collegue @whizcreed to get this working.