# How to implement historyAPI with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, express, scroll

I am trying to build a prototype on lines of qz.com.

Here is the approach:

1. Make a function call to load next piece of content on scrolling to bottom of the page.
2. Same function would change the url using $location.path(url) or window.history.pushState()
3. On scrolling upwards, either of the two will change the url based on the section in display.

I am stuck at point 2. Whenever I call $location or pushState, the page reloads and goes in the loop.

Here is the code:

**Controller**

```
controller('BlogCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $http) {
$scope.blogs = [];
var counter = -1;
$scope.loadNext = function() {      
  $http.get('/api/blogs').success(function(data) {
    //console.log(counter);
    $scope.blogs.push(data[counter]);
    //$location.path('blog/'+data[counter].url);
    //window.history.pushState('blog/'+data[counter].url);
  });
  counter+=1;
}
$scope.loadNext();
```

})

**Directive**

```
directive('scrollLoad', function () {
return function (scope, elm, attr) {
    // Scroll should have been there instead of hover event.
    // For some reason, scroll wasn't being detected, hence used hover function.
    // It is essentially a hack. Need to revisit this piece.
    elm.on('hover', function() {
      window.onscroll = function(ev) {
        if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            scope.$apply(attr.scrollLoad);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

});

**html**

```
div
  div(scroll-load="loadNext()", ng-repeat="blog in blogs")
    h1 {{blog.title}}
    p {{blog.content}}
```

link to repo: https://github.com/fotuzlab/two1/

If you have suggestions for another approach, please answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738428/how-to-execute-infinite-scroll-using-angularjs-and-change-route-on-every-new-po)

Answer (score 0):

Answering self.

Not sure of the logic here, but moving the HTML from partial to index.html worked.

This piece is now part of project Sarus with a modified approach.
https://github.com/srijanlabs/sarus