# jQuery Anchor Based Navigation

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, anchor

I am looking for a way to navigate between pages and respond to events when the anchor changes with jQuery. In order to illustrate my question, let me demonstrate with an example:

1. A user enters a page which has loaded jQuery, without the jQuery UI or any additional plugins.
2. As the page loads, the user is redirected from `http://thesite.com/` to `http://thesite.com/#/`, without any page refresh.
3. A link, like this, is clicked: `<a href="#/author/bio">My Bio</a>`.
4. jQuery uses the `$.ajax()` method to load the requested page, without a page refresh.
5. The user clicks the browser back button, and goes to `http://thesite.com/#/`, without a page refresh.

I am good when it comes to loading the page content. However, here is what I don't know:

1. How do I redirect to `http://thesite.com/#/`, if it is not supplied when the page loads?
2. How do I *listen* for a request to load a page without a refresh, when a link with an anchor divider (#) is clicked?
3. Most importantly, how do I listen for browser back/forward requests, the know what page to load?

Sorry for the crash list of questions. If my scenario wasn't clear enough, then here is a great site that already does it: http://grooveshark.com/.

Thank you for your time! I will reward generously for thorough answers/comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you would have to add an onclick to the a tags.

Then all you have to do is:

```
$('a').click(function(){

    window.location.hash = this.href;
    //some load of that url to the page
    return false;

});
```

And to listen in on hash changes you need a plugin like [this one](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/)

Comment: Hmm... how is cross-browser compatibility with this method?

Comment: @spryno724, which part of it?

Comment: The `window.location.hash` you mentioned above.

Comment: @spryno, that should be cross-browser, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263509/potential-problems-setting-window-location-hash

Answer (score -1):

First load jquery.

on ready change all urls something like

```
$('a').forEach(function(obj){
   obj.href=obj.href+"#";
});
// on click load 
$('a').click(function(a){
   ajaxLoad(a);

//push to window.history

});
```

Comment: all of the a tags already have a `#`, also there is no such thing in jQuery as `forEach`

Comment: my bad I switch between jQuery and dojo :)