# How to store user input urls (anchor links) and redirect user using window.location?

Tags: javascript, url, input, store

I managed to create a condition to detect anchor link,  but after that how do I store the anchor link in my anchor_num variable, so that I can redirect the use to specific url?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    if(window.location.hash){

        var anchor_num = "anchorString";
        window.location = "#"+ anchor_num;

    } else 
          {
            //redirect to default page
          }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By appending or changing hash the browser wouldn't refresh your page. You should call window.location.reload() after you've set the hash:

```
window.location = "#"+ anchor_num;
window.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Get:**

```
 var hash = location.hash.slice(1);
```

**Set:**

```
 location.hash = '#' + 'string';
```

For more information this question may be interesting: [Potential problems setting window.location.hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263509/potential-problems-setting-window-location-hash)