# Rails change page view based on URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

On one projects#index page, I've **3** different views **[Grid, Map, Stats]** and each view has a button. When user clicks any view it sends a **AJAX** Request and load the required content for that view.By **default** the Grid view gets loaded.

now my client wants to directly load the view based of following URL:

```
 www.somedomain.com/projects#grid
 www.somedomain.com/projects#stats
 www.somedomain.com/projects#map
```

But when i check the controller, it doesnt get the information of #grid,#stats and #maps. How we can achieve this in rails. is this possible ? He doesnt want to go with:

```
 www.somedomain.com/projects?view=grid
 www.somedomain.com/projects?view=stats
 www.somedomain.com/projects?view=maps
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is not possible. To your backend application, only the part `www.somedomain.com/projects` from whole `www.somedomain.com/projects#grid` is sent. "Things" after `#` are meant to be for browsers.

Said so - it is meant for web browser - check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298513/4381282) how you can "grab" the hash from url with javascript.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1263520/4381282) is an explanation how you can "get" and "set" values in hash from url - if you would like to manipulate it from your application.

Just to summarise:

```
var myCurrentLocation = window.location.hash.substr(1);

switch (myCurrentLocation) {
    case 'stats':
        $.ajax(/** handler for stats */);
        break;
    case 'map':
        $.ajax(/** handler for map */);
        break;
    default:
        $.ajax(/** handler for grid, and default */);
        break;
}


/*
 * Other code
 */

$('#showStats').click(function () {
    location.hash = '#stats';
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your quick feedback but if we go with Javascipt. it means 2 requests if user have # in the URL. first it will load the default content and then JS will check the # view. and send the request again to render that specific view. right ?

Comment: @Kashif - It depends on how your current application works, but it is possible. Well - as mentioned in answer - you can't send url hash to server. It is just impossible. You can interact with value stored in the hash only in client (web browser). Please, check my answer updated with some conception how you can proceed.